# Select columns in a data.table using vector of characters

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to select some columns from a `data.table` but getting unexpected results.

For the following, I want to select columns `y` and `z` and this works as expected

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=1:4, y=5:8, z=9:6)
dt[, c("y", "z")]
```

When I try to do this using `setdiff` it returns nonsense

```
omit_var <- "x"
dt[, setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var)]
```

Even though they are equivalent `all.equal(setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var), c("y", "z"))`

Why is this happening -- I guessing a scoping issue but can I avoid it while keeping the code similar?

(I realise I can do `i <- setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit); dt[,..i]`)

Comment: It is not a scoping issue. If you call a function in j, data.table can't know that you want to subset. It assumes that you want the return value of the function. You can do `dt[, mget(setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var))]`.

Comment: or `dt[, setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var), with = FALSE]`

Comment: or `dt[, .SD, .SDcols = setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var)]`

Comment: Or `cols <- setdiff(names(dt), omit_var) ; dt[, ..cols]`

Comment: Or `dt[, .SD, .SDcols = -omit_var]`

Comment: Or `dt[, !"x"]` (if you can work without variables)

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg

Comment: You can also cast to `data.frame`: `as.data.frame(dt)[, setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following comments from @Roland: "If you call a function in *j*, data.table can't know that you want to subset. It assumes that you want the return value of the function.". So can use either of

```
dt[, mget(setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var))]
dt[, setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var), with = FALSE]
```

@sindri_baldur gave another alternative using `.SDcols`

```
dt[, .SD, .SDcols = setdiff(c("x","y","z"), omit_var)]
```

And more options from @DavidArenburg

```
dt[, .SD, .SDcols = -omit_var]
```

If you want to keep all columns except the one in a character string you can use

```
dt[, !"x"]
```

Or you could use the `..` operator

```
cols <- setdiff(names(dt), omit_var) 
dt[, ..cols]
```